# How do I set a checkmark in markup?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, markup, jekyll-theme

This is for GitHub pages using the jekyll-theme-tactile theme.

What I have in the .md file is:

```
|             | Create             | Read               | Update             | Delete             |
|-------------|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
| Admin       | :heavy_check_mark: | :heavy_check_mark: | :heavy_check_mark: | :heavy_check_mark: |
```

In [the rendered page](https://davidthielen.github.io/LouisHowe/claims.html), it has the text `:heavy_check_mark:`, not a checkmark. And the table borders are not rendered.

This is all standard markup. Is there something I need to do for GitHub pages or the jekyll-theme-tactile theme?